# skimage submodule importing error

Tags: macos, scikit-image

I have installed scikit-image using

`pip install scikit-image`

on mac os el capitan. Whenever I am importing skimage it works fine. But when I am trying to import submodule `from skimage import data` it is giving following error.

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nilamdhatrak/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
>     Referenced from: /Users/nilamdhatrak/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>    in /Users/nilamdhatrak/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib

I don't understand where the problem is? I am using jupyter notebook and have installed skimage using conda environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your operation system from OS X El Capitan to macOS Sierra or (better) High Sierra, as clock_gettime was added only in macOS 10.12. See [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/182067/import-cv2-throws-symbol-not-found-_clock_gettime/).

Comment: I created another environment in anaconda, import was successful in there, I don't know how. Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: @NilamDhatrak, new image was probably compiled for El Captain or earlier. So the image might be fixed already. Glad you resolved it anyway.